# Use of RecordId in salesforce flows

Tags: salesforce-lightning

why is accountid assigned to recordid in salesforce?

what is really the use of recordid? Why can't we just use accountid in flows to assign variables

Its a concept that I am trying to understand. Why is recordId more important than object id?